# Related to string and substring

Tags: django

What is the efficient way to calculate total number of unique substrings in a string

Answer (score 2):

### Introduction

If we take a look at your double loop below:

```
for i in range(l):
    for j in range(1,l-i+1):
        mylist.append(string[i:j+i])
```

then it becomes clear why your solution terminates with `Runtime Error` for some test cases - the space complexity in the loop is way too high! The number of elements in `mylist` is proportional to n<sup>2</sup>, where `n` is a length of the original string. As per task description, the string length can approach `10^6` characters, your `mylist` size can turn `10^12` respectively.

To make matters worse, elements of `mylist` are not just single characters but substrings of the original string. So, the space complexity is actually O(n<sup>3</sup>). Since your sample input string is of length `5000`, you get way over `512`MB that is the maximum allowed threshold as described [here](https://www.hackerrank.com/environment).

### How to improve space complexity

You must realise that you don't need any `mylist` to count scores of **Stuart** and **Kevin**. Instead, you could just count their scores right in your loop. Why? Because it already generates all substrings of the original string, in which `string[i]` is the first character of the given substring. Then, if it's a vowel, you increment Kevin's score, otherwise - that of Stuart:

```
stuart=0
kevin=0  
for i in range(l):
    for j in range(1,l-i+1):
        if string[i] in vowel:
            kevin += 1
        else:
            stuart += 1
```

### How to improve time complexity

In the previous paragraph, we made a significant improvement because **Runtime Error** is gone, but the solution will still time out for some test cases because its time complexity is still too high - O(n<sup>2</sup>).

To improve it, you must realise that the number of substrings starting with `string[i]` is `len(string) - i`. Hence, there's no need for the inner loop and the original double loop can be simplified to a O(n) time complexity solution:

```
stuart = 0
kevin = 0  
for i in range(l):
    if string[i] in vowel:
        kevin += (l - i)
    else:
        stuart += (l - i)
```

### Full Code

```
def minion_game(string):
    l = len(string)
    vowel=['A','E','I','O','U']

    stuart = 0
    kevin = 0  
    for i in range(l):
        if string[i] in vowel:
            kevin += (l - i)
        else:
            stuart += (l - i)

    if kevin > stuart:
        print(f'Kevin {kevin:d}')
    elif stuart > kevin:
        print(f'Stuart {stuart:d}')
    else:
        print('Draw')
```